# "Init kbd" in putty when wirking with SDL

Tags: ubuntu, sdl, putty

I am trying to execute some code having SDL_Event.

I use Ubuntu CLI on VMware then the code works fine, but when i try to execute the code using putty it is giving me a message "init kbd".

code is able to execute in VMPlayer, but facing problem with putty.

In both cases i am ROOT user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally SDL needs an X11 window for input events.

Install an X server on your VM host and use X-forwarding in PuTTY to launch your SDL program.

Comment: installed X server, when executed "startX" it is showing - `(EE) Failed to load module "vmwgfx" (module does not exist, 0)
(EE) vmware: Please ignore the above warnings about not being able to to load module/driver vmwgfx`

and terminal is waiting infinitely, need to use `ctrl+c` to kill that process.

Comment: You need to install an X server on the VM *host*, not the guest.

Comment: Ohhhh, you already mentioned that, i am a non-sense user.
will try it now.